# How to store a JQuery submitted variable and reuse it at a later stage in a Python/Django project?

Tags: javascript, python, django, slider, jquery-ui-slider

I have developed an application using Python2.7 and Django 1.6 which uses the below slider bar to allow a user to rate various images using a multi page `SessionWizardView` form. The user rating is stored in the variable `value`.

As one of the requirements, each user has to verify the rating they give each image on a later page of the form. Therefore I have to re-display each image along with the slider bar which has to show the same rating the user previously gave the image. E.g. If the user previously rated the image at "+19" the slider has to be set to "+19" the second time the user sees the image.

I have got the application reshowing the images, and I can easily add a slider to each. But I do not know how to get the new slider to start at a previously submitted value. Note: there are multiple images in the same form each of which will require verification.

**Question:** How does one store a JQuery submitted variable and reuse it at a later stage in a Python/Django project?

```
$(function () {
    var initX=0,minX=50,width=400;    
    var slider = $('#slider'),
        tooltip = $('.tooltip');

    slider.slider({
        min: -50,
        max: +50,
        value: 0,

        start: function (event, ui) {
            tooltip.fadeIn('fast');
        },

        slide: function (event, ui) { 
            var value = slider.slider('value'),
                volume = $('.volume');

            console.log(value)

            tooltip.css('left', initX+(value*width)/100).text(ui.value); accordingly
        },

        stop: function (event, ui) {
        },
    });
    initX=slider.slider("value");

    var txt=initX;
   initX+=(minX*width)/100;
tooltip.css('left',initX).text(txt);
});
```

I originally wanted to use a Python/Django slider but was never able to find one that worked well.

Any help, even suggestions of where I should start looking would be very much appreciated. This is my first time building an application so each step is new to me.

Thanks

Comment: I think the general answer is "use a database".

Comment: Are you wanting to persist the data on the frontend or backend?

Comment: @Arvoreniad I am not sure what you mean by 'persist'? I want to store the users final submission in the backend if that helps?

Comment: Right, in that case I think a database is indeed the best option.

Comment: @Pointy I have added a MySQL database as a backend which I am attempting to explore with phpMyAdmin. I am quite new to this but would the submitted value of the JQuery slider be available in the backend until the form as been fully submitted, on the last page?

Comment: I would recommend using PostgreSQL over MySQL. Django's ORM is slightly more efficient with Postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices to persist the value from the post: store it in a database via a Django model instance as @Pointy suggested, or you could hold on to it temporarily in a session, work through the rest of your steps and do whatever you need to do with it.

You can easily pass values from your Django views to JavaScript. This example shows how you could pass in a value that was posted, or use the value from the initial GET.

```
# views.py

def your_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        foo = request.POST.get('foo')
    else:
        foo = 'bar'
    return render('your_template.html', {'foo': foo})

# your_template.html

<p>Some html</p>
<script>
    var foo = '{{ foo }}';
</script>
```

If your JavaScript is in an external file, you can always set the values in a script block that precedes your include so your external file can pick them up:

```
<script>
    var foo = '{{ foo }}';
</script>
<script src="{% static 'js/your-file.js' %}"></script>
```

Hope that helps you out.

Comment: Thanks for the help/suggestions. Firstly I have to use MySQL, but I will keep your suggestion re Postgres for future. I recon that the easiest/quickest solution for me would be to hold it temporarily in the session. Thanks for the example on passing values from Django to JS, but how might I do the opposite as well? So I can get the original value out of the JS slider. Thanks

Comment: You'll need to post the form value(s) to a view, where you can set them into a session. Check out the Django documentation for an example.